# Is there an easier way to generate a multiplication table?

Tags: arrays, exam, tabularray, random

I am trying to find an easier way to generate randomised multiplication tables. I want to keep the formatting exactly as it is- with the table and the lines I have added- etc...
Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have just gone in and added them all myself so far! Thank you for any help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tabularray,paracol}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{5}

\begin{tblr}{|X[1,l]|}
\hline
$11 \times 2$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$6 \times 4$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$8 \times 8$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$3 \times 11$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$9 \times 9$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$7 \times 5$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$10 \times 10$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$4 \times 3$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$2 \times 6$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$5 \times 7$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$11 \times 8$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$8 \times 9$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$6 \times 10$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$3 \times 4$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$9 \times 7$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$7 \times 2$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$10 \times 11$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$4 \times 6$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$2 \times 3$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$5 \times 9$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$11 \times 7$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$8 \times 10$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$6 \times 2$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$3 \times 9$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$9 \times 4$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$7 \times 11$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$10 \times 6$ = \\
\hline 
\end{tblr}

\switchcolumn

\begin{tblr}{|X[1,l]|}
\hline
$4 \times 7$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$2 \times 5$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$5 \times 3$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$11 \times 9$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$8 \times 6$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$6 \times 11$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$3 \times 2$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$9 \times 5$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$7 \times 10$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$10 \times 7$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$4 \times 11$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$2 \times 9$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$5 \times 6$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$11 \times 3$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$8 \times 7$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$6 \times 5$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$3 \times 10$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$9 \times 2$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$7 \times 4$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$10 \times 11$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$4 \times 9$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$2 \times 7$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$5 \times 12$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$11 \times 6$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$8 \times 11$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$6 \times 9$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$3 \times 7$ = \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\switchcolumn

\begin{tblr}{|X[1,l]|}
\hline
$9 \times 3$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$7 \times 8$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$10 \times 5$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$4 \times 2$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$2 \times 10$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$5 \times 4$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$11 \times 12$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$8 \times 5$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$6 \times 7$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$3 \times 12$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$9 \times 1$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$7 \times 6$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$10 \times 9$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$4 \times 5$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$2 \times 8$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$5 \times 11$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$11 \times 5$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$8 \times 12$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$6 \times 3$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$3 \times 6$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$9 \times 10$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$7 \times 1$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$10 \times 4$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$4 \times 10$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$2 \times 6$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$5 \times 8$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$11 \times 11$ = \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\switchcolumn

\begin{tblr}{|X[1,l]|}
\hline
$8 \times 4$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$6 \times 12$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$3 \times 5$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$9 \times 8$ = \\
\hline 
\hline
$7 \times 2$ = \\
\hline 
\end{tblr}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\foo}[2]{\hline\hline$#1 \times #2$}` might help, altough tabulars search of formatting before expanding the macros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `expl3` you have `\int_rand:nn`.

Here's a way to set five multiplication per row, without any tabular or `paracol`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\randommult}{m}
 {% #1 = number of items
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}
  \linespread{1.5}\selectfont
  \tse_randommult:n { #1 }
  \par
  \group_end:
  \addvspace{\topsep}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tse_randommult:n
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \__tse_randommult: }
  \int_compare:nF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 5 } = 0 }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 5 - \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 5 } } { \__tse_randommult_box:Nn \makebox {} }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__tse_randommult:
 {
  \__tse_randommult_box:Nn \framebox { $\int_rand:nn { 1 } { 19 } \times \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 19 } =$ }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__tse_randommult_box:Nn
 {
  #1[\dim_eval:n { (\textwidth - 4em)/5 }][l]{ #2 } \hspace{1em plus 1 fil}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section*{Compute the following seventeen multiplications}

\randommult{17}

\section*{Compute the following ten multiplications}

\randommult{10}

\section*{Compute the following nineteen multiplications}

\randommult{19}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

(I've edited the answer to incorporate the piece of information, provided by the OP in a comment, that the `exam` document class might be used.)

> I am trying to find an easier way to generate randomised multiplication tables. ... Is there a more efficient way to do this?

It's straightforward to achieve the OP's typesetting objective if one is free to use LuaLaTeX. The code given below employs Lua's `for` loop as as well as the `tex.sprint` and `math.random` functions. For an integer `m>2`, `math.random(2,m)` returns uniformly distributed integers in the range from `2` to `m`. In the code used below, I employ `math.random(2,12)`, as the largest integer used in the OP's code appears to be `12`. Note that because the TeX-special character `\` character has a special meaning in Lua, it's necessary to input a backslash character as `\\`.

The following layout follows the one provided in the OP's example: 3 columns with 27 cases, followed by a column with 5 cases. For simplicity, I show just the first 8 rows rather than all 27 rows of the full answer.

[image]

Aside: The Lua code currently draws the pseudo random numbers independently. Since there are 11 distinct integers, there's a 1 in 121 chance that two consecutive cases will be identical. Just such a duplication case has materialized at the top of the third column shown in the screenshot. If this is deemed problematic, a bit of extra code could be added to eliminate such duplication cases.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type

% The Lua function 'myfunc' does most of the work:
\directlua{
```

```lua
  function myfunc ( n )
    tex.sprint ( "\\begin{array}[t]{|wl{2.25cm}|}" )
    for i = 1,n do
      tex.sprint ( "\\hline" .. math.random(2,12) .. "\\times"  
                   .. math.random(2,12) .. "= \\\\ \\hline" )
    end
    tex.sprint ( "\\end{array}" )
  end
```

```tex
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\begin{question}[86] Solve the following multiplication cases. 1 point per case.
\[
\directlua { myfunc(27) } \qquad
\directlua { myfunc(27) } \qquad
\directlua { myfunc(27) } \qquad
\directlua { myfunc(5)  }
\]
\end{question} 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, can I do this using the exam class?

Comment: @user292225 -- I've gone ahead and updated the code in my answer to make it use the `exam` document class. As the screenshot demonstates, LuaLaTeX is perfectly compatible with the `exam` document class.

Comment: How can you avoid multiplying by 1?

Comment: @JLeonV. - Just change both instances of `math.random(12)`(which is equivalent to `math.random(1,12)`) to `math.random(2,12)`. I'll incorporate this thought in an updated answer.

Comment: complete aside: for an exam with 86 items out of 121 possible items, I would probably not use independently drawn entries but take a random shuffle of the items and print the first 86.

Comment: @WillieWong - I fully agree! :-) Let’s see if the OP weighs in with some thoughts or additional requirements.